# How to select variable (with a year in the name) for calculation based on value of a date field using SAS SQL

Tags: sql, db2, sas

With SAS SQL (or just SAS) I need to use a variable for a calculation based on the year portion of a different date field.  The variable's name contains the year that I'd need to match from the year portion of the other date variable.  How can I select the right variable to use for my calculation?

For example, I need to select which one of these to use:

```
GRADE_2013
GRADE_2014
GRADE_2015
```

by looking at a date field of the format `15JAN2014` - so from that year of 2014 I want to grab the value from `GRADE_2014` to use in another calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, one is an array with a year index and another is the VVALUEX function that looks up the value of a variable.

```
Data One;
set Have;
array grades(2013:2015) grade_2013-grade_2015;

*Array method;
variable_want1 = grades(year(date_field));

*VValueX method;
variable_want2 = vvalues('grades_'||put(year(date_field), 4.));
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this sort of problem becomes much easier if you can transpose your data into a more normalized format.

So instead of having three grade_YYYY variables with year suffixes on each, transpose each record into three records, with variables YEAR and GRADE.

Comment: Well, yes, but the fact that she's using SAS implies a reporting database, where data is often selectively denormalized for performance reasons.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  When a SAS programmer receives denormalized data, often their best starting point is to consider the gains that can be obtained by using SAS to normalize it (to some extent). SAS coding is often much simpler with normalized data. There is no reason to be bound by the structures of source data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the great answers...I'm a novice so I'll have to go the non-array approach at least to start.